# Extracting values from an example string given a simple template

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function such as:

```
function extract(template, example){
  //some magic
  return obj;
}
```

That given an input like the following:

```
var template = "/some/path/{param_one}/{another_param}/etc?arg1={value}";
var example = "/some/path/foo/bar/etc?arg1=baz";
```

Would return this object:

```
{param_one: "foo", another_param: "bar", value: "baz"}
```

I don't have control over the template nor the example (e.g. I can't change the template to be a regex with named capture groups). What I can safely assume is that the given example will match the template.

As a start, I was able to extract the keys with this:

```
var re = /\{(.+?)\}/g;
var match;
do {
    match = re.exec(template)
    if (match) {
        console.log(match[1]);
    }
} while (match);
```

Comment: The problem is not well specified. What's the result for `template = "{param_one}{param_two}"; example = "abc";`? Or `template = "{param_one}/{param_two}"; example = "///"`? IF your inputs are ALWAYS url path + query, then it would be solvable.

Comment: @le_m, you are right. You can assume it will always be a path and query, and that two template vars will always be separated at least by `/`, `?`, or `&`. Although the following should be accepted too: `{param_a}/prefix{param_b}/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use regex and replace to solve:

```
function extract(template, example){
  //some magic
  var re = /(?:([^\{]*)\{([^\}]*)\})/g;
  var result = example;
  var params = [];
  var match, values, obj = {};
  do {
    match = re.exec(template)
    if (match) {
      result = result.replace(match[1], '|');
      params.push(match[2]);
    }
  } while (match);
  values = result.split('|');
  for(var i=0;i < params.length; i++) {
    obj[params[i]] = values[i+1];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

First, it get params part and text part use regex, then it replace all text part with `|` and store key to params array.

Finally, it loops through params array and match value splited from above

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I would break this into two parts - build a template object, then use that template object to parse your string(s).  The following function `buildTemplate(pattern)` returns a template object.  You can then use this object to parse as many strings as you need, for example `buildTemplate(pattern).parse(string)` or even `var parser = buildTemplate(pattern); var parameters = parser.parse(string);`.

```
function buildTemplate(pattern) {
    return (function(pattern) {
        function splitString(string) {
            return string.split(/[/?&]+/);
        }

        var glob = {};

        glob.parts = splitString(pattern).map(function(part) {
            var trimmedPart = part.replace(/^\{|\}$/g, '');
            var isLiteral = part.length !== trimmedPart.length + 2;

            return {
                isLiteral: isLiteral,
                value: isLiteral ? part : trimmedPart: 
            };
        });

        glob.parse = function(string) {
            var stringParts = splitString(string);

            if (stringParts.length !== glob.parts.length) {
                return null;
            }

            var params = {};

            for (var i = 0; i < stringParts.length; i++) {
                if (blob.parts[i].isLiteral) {
                    if (blob.parts[i].value !== stringParts[i]) {
                        return null;
                    }
                } else {
                    params[blob.parts[i].value] = stringParts[i];
                }
            }

            return params;
        }

        return glob;
    })(pattern);
}
```

**Note:** This code is completely ***untested***.  Let me know if something doesn't work as intended.